# Using same variable names in different wtfforms in flask

Tags: python, wtforms

In my Flask App I have implemented 2 new forms which contained the same variable names. Both forms were submitted with the same POST request. The result was confusing since the gender data was displayed as the date of birth.

```
class Date_of_birth(Form):
    field_1 = DateField("Date of Birth", format="%Y-%m-%d")


class Gender(Form):
    field_1 = SelectField("Gender", choices=[("Male", "Male"), ("Female", "Female")])
```

When I changed the variables names to "field_1" and "field_2" so they wouldn't be the same, it worked.

So I assume that multiple WTFs containing same variable names cannot be submitted in a single POST request, but must have different variable names?
If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

When a web browser POSTs HTML form data back to the server it looks like this:

```
field_1=2000-01-01&field_1=Female
```

The data only contains field  names and their corresponding values, so there is no way for the server to determine which name/value pair to assign to which form if there are multiple forms with conflicting field names.  Thus, you need to use different field names in the html to ensure that the server can assign the right values to the right form on POST.

However wtforms provides a solution to this problem.  The [form class](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form.__init__) accepts a *prefix* argument:

> **prefix** – If provided, all fields will have their name prefixed with the value

So you can instantiate your forms like this:

dob = Date_of_birth(prefix='dob')
gender = Gender(prefix='gender')

Input element HTML will include the prefix:

```
<input id="dob-field_1" name="dob-field_1" type="text" value="">
```

and so will the POST data:

```
dob-field_1=2000-01-01&gender-field_1=Female
```

and wtforms will automatically extract the correct values based on *prefix*:

```
>>> # Post data is usually in a MultiDict - a kind of dict that can have
>>> multiple values for a single key.

>>> data = MultiDict([('dob-field_1', '2000-01-01'), ('gender-field_1', 'Female')])
>>> dob = Date_of_birth(data, prefix='dob')  
>>> dob.validate()
True
>>> dob.data
{'field_1': datetime.date(2000, 1, 1)}


>>> gender = Gender(data, prefix='gender')
>>> gender.validate()
True
>>> gender.data
{'field_1': 'Female'}
```